# Is it possible to start elastic search using java without installing it in local machine?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I did a java application to do simple elastic search operations... I need to start elastic search before running it. I don't want my client to do the same. is there any ways to start elastic search using java?, without the need of install it in local machine?

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to run embedded Elasticsearch these days, no

you need to have it installed (package or tar.gz) and then directly invoke it